# Android equivalent of iOS "scale to fill"

Tags: android, ios, uiimageview

I'm currently working on migrating my iOS app to Android. On my UIImageViews I'm using "scale to fill" content mode. What is Androids equivalent of "scale to fill"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set Scale of Image View in android via using below code

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

There are many other properties available for Image

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Use according to  your need. Hope this helps you'